# React js How to get Value within a useEffect and display on defualtValue textfield

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of `userData` which is from a promise in firebase and set that value on my `TextField` `defaulValue` when the page loads. But the page loads first before the value can be placed which makes it `default:undefined`. How can I make my page load with the `defaultValue`?[image: consoleLog]

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField} from '@mui/material';
import { useAuth } from '../../contexts/AuthContext';
import { db } from '../../firebase'
import { getDoc, doc } from '@firebase/firestore';


export default function useEditUser() {

    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [newDisplayName,setDisplayName] = useState("");
    const documentId = currentUser.uid
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{
        const getUsers = async()=>{
            const docRef =  doc(db, "user", documentId)
            await getDoc(docRef).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data().user_fields)
                setUserData(res.data().user_fields)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
        getUsers()
    },[]);
    

    return (
        
        <form>
            <Grid container columnSpacing={1} rowSpacing={1} direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" marginBottom={1}>
                <Grid item xs={11} sm={8} md={3}>
                    <TextField defaultValue={console.log("default:" + userData.displayname)} error={newDisplayName===""} defaultValue={userData.displayname} helperText={newDisplayName === "" ? 'Required' : ' '} label="User Display Name*" id="outlined-required" type="text" variant="outlined"  onChange={(event) => {setDisplayName(event.target.value)}} sx={{width: '100%'}} />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>     
        </form>
            
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loading state with default value true to render the `textField` when `loading` is `false` and when you get the data from the api then you will set the `loading` to `false`. Which will render that field with default value that you want Refer to the following code

```
export default function useEditUser() {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [newDisplayName,setDisplayName] = useState("");
    const documentId = currentUser.uid
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const [loading,setLoading]=useState(true)

    useEffect(() =>{
        const getUsers = async()=>{
            setLoading(true);
            const docRef =  doc(db, "user", documentId)
            await getDoc(docRef).then(res => {
                console.log(res.data().user_fields)
                setUserData(res.data().user_fields)
                setLoading(false)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setLoading(false)
            })
        }
        getUsers()
    },[]);
    

    return (
        
        <form>
            <Grid container columnSpacing={1} rowSpacing={1} direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" marginBottom={1}>
                <Grid item xs={11} sm={8} md={3}>
                   {!loading? <TextField defaultValue={console.log("default:" + userData.displayname)} error={newDisplayName===""} defaultValue={userData.displayname} helperText={newDisplayName === "" ? 'Required' : ' '} label="User Display Name*" id="outlined-required" type="text" variant="outlined"  onChange={(event) => {setDisplayName(event.target.value)}} sx={{width: '100%'}} /> :""}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>     
        </form>   
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this helps. I guess I should just wrap the entire thing in an on loading cause I also have to do it for more textfields. But thanks so much this makes me move forward with this project

Comment: Yes, you should wrap the entire code in the loading state. Always make sure to show data when it's loaded otherwise you will get into a lot of errors. Do give an upvote to my answer if it helped. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

At bottom in render just add the question mark: `userData?.displayname`

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` is used to insert data when you don't have the data yet. In your case, it doesn't even need to be populated, `value` needs to be.
In the defaultValue and value props, you need to specify strings, but in your code you are putting functions. Also, you cannot use objects, unless you stringify them with `JSON.stringify(userData)`. You also need to specify the prop only once.

So you can use something like this:

```js
    return (
        
        <form>
            <Grid container columnSpacing={1} rowSpacing={1} direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" marginBottom={1}>
                <Grid item xs={11} sm={8} md={3}>
                    <TextField value={userData?.displayname} sx={{width: '100%'}} />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>     
        </form>
            
    )
```